# Spring Boot-Log4J2: Is there any way to use the values in application.yml for JDBC appender?

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to create a JDBC appender to log into a DB table. I've succeeded so far by creating a ConnectionFactory and specifying it in `log4j2-spring.xml`. However, the DB credentials are all hardcoded and I would like to use the credentials I have in my `application.yml` but since logging seems to be loaded before Spring ApplicationContext, using the @Value annotation doesn't work.

I've also tried building the appender programmatically with [this guide](http://smasue.github.io/log4j2-spring-database-appender) as a reference but it's requiring me to define the extended `LifeCycle` methods in ConnectionSource and I'm not sure what to do with that.

I've tried defining the ConnectionSource class as this but it returns a NullPointerException on this line

```
Appender jdbcAppender = JdbcAppender.newBuilder()
                .setBufferSize(0)
                .setColumnConfigs(columnConfigs)
                .setColumnMappings()
                .setConnectionSource(connectionSource)
                .setTableName("LOG")
                .setName("databaseAppender")
                .setIgnoreExceptions(true)
                .setFilter(null)
                .build();
```

This is the ConnectionSource I made:

```
    public class LoggerDatabaseSource implements ConnectionSource
    {
        private DataSource dataSource;


        public LoggerDatabaseSource(String url, String userName, String password, String validationQuery)
        {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("user", userName);
            properties.setProperty("password", password);

            GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection> pool = new GenericObjectPool<>();
            DriverManagerConnectionFactory cf = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(url, properties);
            new PoolableConnectionFactory(cf, pool, null, validationQuery, 3, false, false, Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
            this.dataSource = new PoolingDataSource(pool);
        }

        @Override
        public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
        {
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        }

        @Override
        public State getState() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize() {

        }

        @Override
        public void start() {

        }

        @Override
        public void stop() {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isStarted() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isStopped() {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you aren't using one of Log4j's database appenders? If you want access to properties defined in Spring's configuration, if you are using Spring Boot you can use the [Log4j Spring Cloud Config Client](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-spring-cloud-config/log4j-spring-cloud-config-client/index.html) which provides the [Spring Lookup](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#SpringLookup). This will let you reference properties from your application.yml file and use them in your log4j configuration.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as @Yanyan. I tried going the route of defining a **JdbcAppender** in the **log4j2.xml** file, but the issue is that I need to use a connection pool as such the only way that I could see to do that was to use a **ConnectionFactory**. But I was not able to find a way to load my connection details from the **application.yml** file in a static way as is needed for this method. When the static method is called to acquire a **Connection**, the **Spring Boot application** has not yet completed initializing.